# Upload file on Dropbox using REST api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, dropbox-api

Below code uploads files on a server with same name, size and file type (like it's uploading a dummy file). But when do I try to view it, it shows noting. When I try to upload a `.txt` file it works. What's wrong?

```
public static void UploadFile(string accessToken,string path,HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            try
            {

                var client = new RestClient("https://content.dropboxapi.com/1/files_put/auto/Abc/" + file.FileName);
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.PUT);
                request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", file.ContentType);
                //request.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.ContentLength.ToString());                               
                request.AddFile("file", path);

                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume from the classes I see that you're using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/)? I'm not all that familiar, but from a quick search, it doesn't look like `AddFile` does what you want. (That sets up a multipart form upload, which is not what the Dropbox API expects.)

Instead of `request.AddFile(...)`, I think you want something like this (completely untested):

```
// Get a byte array of the file content. Note that this involves reading
// the entire file into memory! I couldn't immediately find a way to work
// with the stream itself in RestSharp.
MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
file.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
byte[] data = target.ToArray();

// Send those bytes as the body of your HTTP request.
request.AddParameter("application/octet-stream", data, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Comment: Thanks for interest.
I have already tried this,but it had not worked.

Comment: its create a file there but when i want preview it display nothing and also when i check file size , file size in Bytes

Comment: What was the file size? Was it the same size as the file you were trying to store? Larger? Smaller? What did the actual contents of the file look like (e.g. if you `type` the file from the command-line)?

Comment: Like, If I upload a 8kb file,but when i check file size on dropbox its show 13 bytes

Comment: That happens with the code I suggested? What are the 13 bytes?

Comment: yes, its happens with the code you suggested and 13 Bytes are filesize which file i had uploaded.

Comment: I'm asking what are the 13 bytes? What is the first byte? And the second? Etc. You can `type` the file from the command-line to look at it.

Comment: I'd also suggest logging the size of the byte array (`data` in my code above) so you can see how many bytes are being sent in the web request.